# Using an if-else statement to at any point make the program end

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am creating a simple program that takes some input and turns it into an output to .txt file.

I have been trying to use if-else statements to make it so that after it has received a name ;

```
//user enters name and then moves to next line
System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
```

it will either move onto the next part (if a name is entered) or break. 
How and where will i properly add and format these if-else statements? thanks you

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.*;



public class JavaProject {

    private static char[] input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int b = 1; b < 100; b++ ) { 
            //this is making the code loop 100 times

            //variables 
            int[] minutesPlayed = new int [100];
            String gamerName, gamerReport;

            //Main data storage arrays
            String[] gameNames = new String[100];
            int[] highScores = new int[100];

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            //formatting for output and input
            System.out.println("////// Game Score Report Generator \\\\\\\\\\\\");
            System.out.println("     ");

            //user enters name and then moves to next line
            System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
            gamerName = Scan.nextLine();

            //user is given an example of input format 
            System.out.println("FALSE DATA FORMAT WILL CAUSE ERROR - Input Gamer Information " + "Using Format --> Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
            System.out.println("    ");

            //another data input guide which is just above where data input is in console
            System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
            gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();


            String[] splitUpReport; // an array of string
            splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":"); // split the text up on the colon

            int i = 0;

            //copy data from split text into main data storage arrays 
            gameNames[i] = splitUpReport[0];
            highScores[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim() );
            minutesPlayed[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());




            //output to file using a PrintWriter using a FileOutPutStream with append set to true within the printwriter constructor
            //

           try
           {

              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Gaming Report Data", true));
              writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
              writer.println();
              writer.println("--------------------------------");
              writer.println();
              String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
              writer.println("Game: " + report[0] + ", score= " +report[1] + ", minutes played= " +report[2]);
              writer.println();
              writer.close();

          } catch (IOException e)
          {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
          }    
        }                   

    }

    public static char[] getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public static void setInput(char[] input) {
        JavaProject.input = input;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I dont see an if-else ladder anywhere in your code

Comment: Instead of a for loop that goes 100 times, just use a while loop. i.e. boolean shouldKeepRunning = true; while(shouldKeepRunning) {/*everything in your for loop goes here*/}. Then if you encounter the bad input that means you need to quit running/looping, just set shouldKeepRunning = false, and then your program should exit.

Comment: `if (gamerName().equals("")) {...} else {...}` maybe?

Comment: What is your question? BTW you should really avoid this meaningless comments like `//this is making the code loop 100 times` or `//variables `. They don't add much to the understanding of code.

Comment: It's also not correct, as the code is looping 99 times :)

Comment: @matmo how would I go about doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this function in your main class, and every time you want to ask a user for a name, call it. Additionally, you'll have to declare your scanner outside of your main function.

```
public String getName(){
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    if(name.equals("whatever it is you want to end program"))
        System.exit(0);
    else
        return name;
}
```

To implement this, you would make this method outside your main method. Then, each time you do

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

instead, do

```
getName();
```

Comment: How do i properly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can put it right after the Scan.nextline. If you want the program to break, you can throw an exception. You could also make a loop, and ask for the name for as long as the user does not give one.